# JQuery UI - Using Widgets Polymorphically

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I was planning on creating several widgets using JQuery UI, and use them polymorphically.

So, say I have two widgets called widget_1 and widget_2, both of which define a "public" method called testMethod().  I would like to blindly take either object and call the testMethod.  Something like:

```
widget.testMethod()
```

However, JQuery seems to require that I know which object I have since the syntax for calling a method uses the form:

```
$("#widget_1").widget_1("testMethod");
```

and

```
$("#widget_2").widget_2("testMethod");
```

Are there any other options I have to be able to use widgets polymorphically?

Thanks.

Comment: After some reading, I'm planning on switching to Mootools. JQuery seems to be more focused on DOM manipulation and not code organization and OO which I need.

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended, but you could accomplish it like this:

```
$.fn.testMethod = function(param1, param2){
   var id = this.attr("id");  //'this' references the selected element(s)
   return this;
};
```

Then you could do:

```
$("#widget_1").testMethod('foo', 'bar');
```

But you would be polluting the $ "namespace"